# How do i copy and paste and objects location,rotation and scale at the same time

Tags: animation, camera

I have notice that when i do animations and make a mistake on where the camera should be its hard to fix it due to how long it takes to change its Locrotscale.
is there a faster way to copy it all and paste it to another frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 'camera' object selected, go to the 'dope sheet' editor window. Select the key-frames you want to duplicate and press Shift+D. Then press G to grab and drag the new keys to the desired frame. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

While it is no one-click solution the [Copy Attributes Menu Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu) comes in handy for transferring locrotscale from one object to another. It comes with Blender but you have to activate it in User Preferences -> Add-ons (search for "attribute").

If activated you can select your target object, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Select your source object, hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and select whatever option you want to copy first. Unfortunately there is no option to transfer all three options at once.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a Pose IK, from one armature to another -- for example to have hands meet at a particular frame?